# JavaScript: is it possible to POST JavaScript variable as file

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have a JSON variable in JavaScript "**tabledata**" which I post using simple Ajax Post. But in my server if size of POST request is > 2MB than it throws error. This **tabledata** JSON object is generated through various JavaScript processes. Can I store content of this JSON object in file automatically and POST it as file upload as my server allow 50MB of file upload?

Comment: It's possible, but my question would be, why would you do that? If you have 50mb of JSON to send, there's probably an issue of trying to do way too much with one API call.

Comment: @Shilly The file size varies, it can be 10 MB but not more. The functionality is just dumping HTML table in JSON format to server to store.